# SQL SUM First 5 rows per reference then all other rows per reference treated as 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tricky sql query where I require to SUM the first 5 weight rows per type per reference. I have this sorted in the code below. The next step is to treat all other weights per reference outside of the first 5 as a value of 1 and add to the Total_Weight.

So if the 'first 5' SUM total is 20 for that reference and there is 10 more rows (weights) for that reference the Total_Weight for that reference would be 30 regardless of the actual weight values.

```
SELECT B.wsf_ref,
SUM(T_wsf_value) Total_wsf_value,
group_concat(concat('TOP 5 ',B.type,' (',B.T,')') SEPARATOR ' ') Details
FROM
(
SELECT id, wsf_ref, status, type, SUM(wsf_value) T_wsf_value,group_concat(wsf_value SEPARATOR '+') T
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT id, wsf_ref, type, status, CASE WHEN @wsf_ref = wsf_ref THEN @ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1 ELSE @ROW_NUMBER := 1 END AS rn,wsf_value,@wsf_ref := wsf_ref
        FROM individual,(SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 1, @wsf_ref := ''
    ) r
    WHERE type= 'Pike' AND status= 'Approved' ORDER BY wsf_ref, id ASC
    )A WHERE rn < 6


    UNION ALL

    SELECT * FROM
    (
      SELECT id, wsf_ref, type, status, CASE WHEN @wsf_ref = wsf_ref THEN @ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1 ELSE @ROW_NUMBER := 1 END AS rn,wsf_value,@wsf_ref := wsf_ref
      FROM individual,(SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 1, @wsf_ref := ''
  ) r
  WHERE type= 'Zander' AND status= 'Approved' ORDER BY wsf_ref, id ASC
    )A WHERE rn < 6


    UNION ALL

    SELECT * FROM
    (
      SELECT id, wsf_ref, type, status, CASE WHEN @wsf_ref = wsf_ref THEN @ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1 ELSE @ROW_NUMBER := 1 END AS rn,wsf_value,@wsf_ref := wsf_ref
      FROM individual,(SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 1, @wsf_ref := ''
  ) r
  WHERE type= 'Asp' AND status= 'Approved' ORDER BY wsf_ref, id ASC
    )A WHERE rn < 6


    UNION ALL

    SELECT * FROM
    (
      SELECT id, wsf_ref, type, status, CASE WHEN @wsf_ref = wsf_ref THEN @ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1 ELSE @ROW_NUMBER := 1 END AS rn,wsf_value,@wsf_ref := wsf_ref
      FROM individual,(SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 1, @wsf_ref := ''
  ) r
  WHERE type= 'Chub' AND status= 'Approved' ORDER BY wsf_ref, id ASC
    )A WHERE rn < 6


    UNION ALL

    SELECT * FROM
    (
      SELECT id, wsf_ref, type, status, CASE WHEN @wsf_ref = wsf_ref THEN @ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1 ELSE @ROW_NUMBER := 1 END AS rn,wsf_value,@wsf_ref := wsf_ref
      FROM individual,(SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 1, @wsf_ref := ''
  ) r
  WHERE type= 'Perch' AND status= 'Approved' ORDER BY wsf_ref, id ASC
    )A WHERE rn < 6


)A
GROUP BY wsf_ref, type
)B
GROUP BY wsf_ref
ORDER BY Total_wsf_value DESC
```

Can I do this in the current structure I have?

```
Sample Data
  ID     WSF_REF    TYPE    WEIGHT
 -----------------------------------
  1        1        Pike      10  *
  2        1        Pike      10  *
  3        1        Pike      10  *
  4        1        Pike      10  *
  5        1        Pike      10  *
  6        1        Pike      10   Treated as value 1.
  7        1        Asp       10  *
  8        1        Asp       10  *
  9        1        Asp       10  *
  10       1        Asp       10  *
  11       1        Asp       10  *
  12       1        Asp       10  Treated as value 1.
  13       2        Pike      10  *
```

The results would be as follows

```
 WSF_REF    Total_Weight
 -------------------------
    1           102
    2           10
```

Comment: Is "first 5 weight rows" determined by the `ID` value?

Comment: Yes My SQL and yes. The ASC order of the ID's determine first 5.

Comment: MySQL Version 5.6.43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you your desired results. It is compatible with all versions of MySQL. It forms a `UNION` of two tables, one with all the rows with an effective row number of 1 to 5 for each `WSF_REF`/`TYPE` combination, the other with all the other rows. For the first table, the raw weights are used, for the second a value of 1 is substituted. This table is then used as a subquery for a query which `SUM`s `WEIGHT` by `WSF_REF`:

```
SELECT WSF_REF, SUM(WEIGHT)
FROM (SELECT t1.ID, t1.WSF_REF, t1.TYPE, t1.WEIGHT
      FROM test t1
      LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.WSF_REF = t1.WSF_REF AND t2.TYPE = t1.TYPE AND t2.ID < t1.ID
      GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.WSF_REF, t1.TYPE, t1.WEIGHT
      HAVING COUNT(t2.ID) < 5 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT t1.ID, t1.WSF_REF, t1.TYPE, 1
      FROM test t1
      LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.WSF_REF = t1.WSF_REF AND t2.TYPE = t1.TYPE AND t2.ID < t1.ID
      GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.WSF_REF, t1.TYPE
      HAVING COUNT(t2.ID) >= 5) t
GROUP BY WSF_REF
```

Output:

```
WSF_REF SUM(WEIGHT)
1       102
2       10
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h53dUZPFnC2hGr4xZQCXsq/0)

**Update**

To ignore rows where `STATUS` is not `'Approved'` the derived table query needs to be updated to include that as a `WHERE` condition and also add matching `STATUS` values to the `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT WSF_REF, SUM(WEIGHT)
FROM (SELECT t1.ID, t1.WSF_REF, t1.TYPE, t1.WEIGHT
      FROM test t1
      LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.WSF_REF = t1.WSF_REF AND t2.TYPE = t1.TYPE AND t2.STATUS = t1.STATUS AND t2.ID < t1.ID
      WHERE t1.STATUS = 'Approved'
      GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.WSF_REF, t1.TYPE, t1.WEIGHT
      HAVING COUNT(t2.ID) < 5 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT t1.ID, t1.WSF_REF, t1.TYPE, 1
      FROM test t1
      LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.WSF_REF = t1.WSF_REF AND t2.TYPE = t1.TYPE AND t2.STATUS = t1.STATUS AND t2.ID < t1.ID
      WHERE t1.STATUS = 'Approved'
      GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.WSF_REF, t1.TYPE
      HAVING COUNT(t2.ID) >= 5) t
GROUP BY WSF_REF
```

[Updated demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h53dUZPFnC2hGr4xZQCXsq/2)

Comment: You my friend are a legend. However, I have been a muppet. I completely forgot the  WHERE STATUS = 'Approved' for each entry. Where would I add that in the above statement?

Comment: @MarkHarraway you would only want to count weights `WHERE STATUS = 'Approved'`?

Comment: yes that is correct. So the same as you have posted but if STATUS is not 'Approved' they are ignored completely.

Comment: @MarkHarraway See my edit, that should do what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193574/discussion-between-mark-harraway-and-nick).

Comment: working like a treat. I have the scenario now where two wsf_ref are linked together with the same wsf_team_id. Is it possible to group by wsf_team_id? The parameters are still the same (first 5 id’s per wsf_ref per type then 1 after) just the two wsf_ref totals are summed together to form a team total.

Comment: @MarkHarraway it's hard to be certain without seeing sample data, but if `WSF_TEAM_ID` is in the same table as `WSF_REF` you should be able to simply replace `WSF_REF` in the query with `WSF_TEAM_ID`. If that doesn't work, perhaps you could update my [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h53dUZPFnC2hGr4xZQCXsq/2) to include some sample data showing the problem.

Comment: I tried updating but it wouldn't save. WSF_TEAM groups two WSF_REF's together. Same criteria as current (First 5 per WSF_REF per type then 1 for each) but now WSF_TEAM_ID groups the WSF_REFS.

Comment: @MarkHarraway if you can't update the demo it's probably simpler just to ask a new question and put the updated sample data in it with your new expected output.

Comment: Thanks. New question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56321391/first-5-rows-summed-per-ref-per-type-all-others-equal-1-grouped-by-a-team-id

Comment: @MarkHarraway I forgot about also adding `TEAMID` to the inner `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h53dUZPFnC2hGr4xZQCXsq/17

Comment: Thanks nick, I tried the code in the other answer which is similar to yours and it works perfectly. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question contains `group_concat` function, so I assume you are using MySql (because only MySql has a functioion with that name).
In MySql 8.0 and higher you can try this query:

```
SELECT WSF_REF,
       SUM( CASE WHEN cnt <= 5 THEN WEIGHT ELSE 1 END ) as Total_Weight
FROM (
  SELECT t.*,
        row_number() over (partition by `WSF_REF`, `TYPE` ORDER BY `ID` ) as cnt
  FROM Table1 t
) x
GROUP BY WSF_REF
```

demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80787ce0493cefc9a3eb52bb36821a5e

**----------
EDIT
----------**

Use this query in MySql 5.6:

```
SELECT WSF_REF,
       SUM( CASE WHEN cnt <= 5 THEN WEIGHT ELSE 1 END ) as Total_Weight
FROM (
   SELECT t.*,
          (@t:=if(@ws=wsf_ref AND @typ=TYPE, @t+1, 1)) cnt,
          @ws:=wsf_ref, @typ:=TYPE
   FROM Table1 t
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @t:=0, @ws:='', @typ:='') x
   ORDER BY t.wsf_ref, t.type
) x
GROUP BY WSF_REF
```

demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c423d2f98e6f43d1d2d7d5794ba75c1c

Comment: Unfortunately currently 5.6.43-cll-lve

Comment: I've updated the answer with an examle how to do it in MySql 5.6